# Tailwind doesn't apply styles on components in pages folder

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

**NextJS** project has been created already with tailwind support so I didn't set up it by myself

When I add `className` on html element on component in `pages/` folder it simply doesn't work even thought **Elements** panel in **DevTools** shows that `className` is present

I tried to add a component in `src/app/` directory with **tailwind classes** and it works fine

I saw somewhere in answers for the same problem that probably path **pages/** is not present in **tailwind.config.js** but it is added in my config

here is code:

**UPD:**
**layout.tsx:**

```js
import './globals.css'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

**tailwind.config.js:**

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}', // Note the addition of the `app` directory.
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',

    // Or if using `src` directory:
    './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**globals.css:**

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

here is usage in **pages/news/[category].tsx:**

```js
export default function ArticleListByCategory({ articles, category }: { articles: Article[], category: string }): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <>
            <h1>Showing news for catgory <i>{category}</i></h1>
            {
                articles.map((article: Article) => (
                    <div key={article.id}>
                                       \/\/\/\/\/\/\/
                        <h2 className="text-red-500">
                            {article.id} {article.title}
                        </h2>
                        <p>{article.description}</p>
                        <hr />
                    </div>
                ))
            }
        </>
    )
}
```

and here is what I see on the site:
[image]

However, here is **src/app/example** route code:
**src/app/example/page.tsx:**

```js
export default function Example(): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <>
            <h1 className="text-red-500">Hello</h1>
        </>
    )
}
```

and here is result for **/example/**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*To get this*

[image: desired result]

**Please read this section**

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors

> If you’d like to completely replace the default color palette with your own custom colors, add your colors directly under the theme.colors section of your configuration file:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    colors: {
      transparent: 'transparent',
      current: 'currentColor',
      'white': '#ffffff',
      'purple': '#3f3cbb',
      'midnight': '#121063',
      'metal': '#565584',
      'tahiti': '#3ab7bf',
      'silver': '#ecebff',
      'bubble-gum': '#ff77e9',
      'bermuda': '#78dcca',
    },
  },
}
```

If you want to use their different variants then you can do something like that

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    colors: {
      transparent: 'transparent',
      current: 'currentColor',
      'white': '#ffffff',
      'tahiti': {
        100: '#cffafe',
        200: '#a5f3fc',
        300: '#67e8f9',
        400: '#22d3ee',
        500: '#06b6d4',
        600: '#0891b2',
        700: '#0e7490',
        800: '#155e75',
        900: '#164e63',
      },
      // ...
    },
  },
}
```

Now you can use it like that

```
<h2 class="text-tahiti-500">Some Text</h2>
```

**UPDATE**

To use tailwindcss for the pages folder, we should do the following

Add an _app.js file under the pages folder and import styles

```
import '../styles/globals.css';

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
    return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default App;
```

Add a test folder under the pages folder and then add an index.tsx file under newly generated test folder

```
const Test = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <h1 className="text-tahiti-500">Hello</h1>
        </>
    )
}

export default Test;
```

Build the entire application again

```
npm run build
```

Then start your application and navigate to localhost:3000/test

[image: final result]

Comment: There are two cases in the question: in first case I use `text-red-500` and it doesn't work in `pages/` folder, and after that I use `text-red-500` in `src/app/` folder and it works. The colours are the same

Comment: App and Pages folders.. That made me think that you're using NextJs. If it is so, do not forget to activate experimental features of NextJs 13 by adding this line into your next.config.js file --> experimental: { appDir: true } (Just a guess)

Comment: I've mentioned on the first line that this is **NextJS** project) I've added but still nothing :/

Comment: Please use this version of tailwindcss and try again --> 3.2.4

Comment: Hey, one thing: your app folder should be in root level. You said it is under src folder.

Comment: As this project is created via `npx create-next-app@latest`, **NextJS** sets folder by its own. For your comments above: Tailwindcss@3.2.4 installed -> **issue not resolved**. experimental property added -> **issue not resolved**

Comment: Then we should inject tailwind styles into your app.js file as we did for page folder

Comment: Yes, I have found it. Coming.. Check for my updated answer.

Comment: Hey @Lvasche , you made it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254248/discussion-between-lvasche-and-ahmet-firat-keler).